# Dynamically adding of Series in Apex Chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I had result that was pulled from the database, and each item in the result is a series in a single chart.

I was able to update that chart but the last element of the result only shows in the chart. What could be the possible problem for this one?

```
for (i = 0; i < objResult.length; i++) {
    temperatureRender.updateSeries([{
        name: objResult[i].TankName,
        data: objResult[i].TankLogs
    }]);
}
```

It displays the Series but only the last series that I've added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `updateSeries` method [*overwrites* the existing series](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries). So in a for loop (like in the code you've included) you'd only be showing the last element - overriding any previous ones.

Take a look at the `appendSeries` method instead which will allow you to [add additional series](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#appendSeries), while keeping the already existing.

Just worth mentioning as well, that this is different from `appendData` which allows you to [add additional data points](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#appendData) to an already existing series.

Comment: Do  ineed to clear the series again after appendSeries?. Im getting a t.push is not a function after rerunning the code. Since the appendSeries will be put inside a loop to rerun on a certain period of time.

Comment: I've not come across that error. Might have to do with the scoping of the chart? Can you reproduce it in a codepen?

Comment: Is it also possible to update xaxis categories simultaneously? @OscarSchafer

Comment: @SampleTest Take a look at the [updateSeries](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries) docs - there's a tiny comment about updating both series and options together. You can pass both your new categories and series as part up the [updateOptions](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions) method.